# 2 number subtracted from each other make a NaN?

Tags: javascript, nan

i'm trying to subtract 2 integers from each other, but i'm keep getting `NaN`.
Can anyone please explain what is wrong with my code

```
var moveit = null;
p = function (e){

if ((e.target.id == "windowContainer") || (e.target.id == 
"windowContainer2") || (e.target.id == "windowContainer3")){
    console.log (e);
    window.moveit = e.target;
    window.onmousemove = p2;
    var r = window.moveit.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rl = r.left;
    var rt = r.top;

    window.onmouseup = function (e){
    if (window.moveit == null) return;
        window.moveit.onmousemove = window.moveit = null;
    }
}
}

p2 = function (e, rt, epageY){  
    if (window.moveit == null) return;
    var newY = rt - e.pageY;
    console.log(isNaN(newY));
}
document.getElementById('windowContainer').onmousedown = p;
document.getElementById('windowContainer2').onmousedown = p;
document.getElementById('windowContainer3').onmousedown = p;
```

Comment: Why do you think you have two integers? `rt` doesn't have any value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The onmousemove/down functions only pass one argument to their handlers - an `Event` object. In this case, `e` is the only defined argument in `p2`. Call the function yourself like this to test that it's working:

```
p2({pageY: 100}, 50)
```

will log `false`.

Comment: @Collin Here is a working example on top of this answer, which is basically what I wanted to answer :) [EXAMPLE](https://jsfiddle.net/a58bysjg/)

Answer (score 0):

`rt` is not a value, this is causing your problems. You need to pass it into your `onmousemove` event

```
var moveit = null;
p = function(e) {
  if (
    e.target.id == "windowContainer" ||
    e.target.id == "windowContainer2" ||
    e.target.id == "windowContainer3"
  ) {
    console.log(e);
    window.moveit = e.target;
    var r = window.moveit.getBoundingClientRect();
    var rl = r.left;
    var rt = r.top;
    window.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
      p2(e, rt);
    });
    window.onmouseup = function(e) {
      if (window.moveit == null) return;
      window.moveit.onmousemove = window.moveit = null;
    };
  }
};

p2 = function(e, rt, epageY) {
  if (window.moveit == null) return;
  var newY = rt - e.pageY;
  console.log(newY);
};
document.getElementById("windowContainer").onmousedown = p;
document.getElementById('windowContainer2').onmousedown = p;
document.getElementById('windowContainer3').onmousedown = p;
```

This block of code will work properly. Here is the list of things I changed:

1. I added addEventListener instead of .onmousemove, I consider this better coding style, but you can do as you wish (the performance difference is minimal to none).
2. In the mousemove event I created an anonymous function so that you can pass in rt from the value you calculated above.